# How to synchronise a timer for everyone client

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a working timer, but it runs from 25 seg every time who the website is visited by a client, I want to synchronise it. F.E. if i visit my webpage in mY Pc, and when it show 15seg left, i visit it from other pc and i want it to show 15 left too.

```
function timerr(){
    var initial = 25000;
    var count = initial;
    var counter;
    var initialMillis;

    function timer() {
        if (count <= 0) {
            clearInterval(counter); 
            return;
        }
        var current = Date.now();

        count = count - (current - initialMillis); 
        initialMillis = current;
        displayCount(count);

    function displayCount(count) {
        var res = count / 1000;
        if (res<0.1){
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "";
        }
        else{
            tiempo = res.toPrecision(count.toString().length);
            tiempo_corto = tiempo.slice(0,-1);
            document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = tiempo_corto;
    }
    }
    clearInterval(counter);
    initialMillis = Date.now();
    counter = setInterval(timer, 10);
}
```

Comment: If I understand you right, this can't be done without a custom server coordinating everything. The server will have the single source of truth (it knows how much time is left in the timer), and each client will need to ask the server for this information when they first load the page.

Comment: Also, what are the events that'll start and stop this global timer? Can anyone start this global timer, which impacts all visitors to the site? Or is there something else that causes the timer to start? This may impact what solution works best in your scenario.

Comment: the global timer is automatic, when there are 0 secs left, its start from 25 sec again. Its for a roulette. I have a sql database connexted to my website but i dont know how to create the function for the global timer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everyone to have the same timer count down every 25 seconds and stop at the exact same time, then you can simply use timestamps to keep everything in sync. Here's an example countdown timer that'll restart every 6 seconds (from 5 to 0) and will hit zero at the exact same time for everyone (unless their computer clock is off).

```js
const timerElement = document.getElementById('timer')
const TIMER_DURATION = 6

function step() {
  const timestamp = Date.now() / 1000
  const timeLeft = (TIMER_DURATION - 1) - Math.round(timestamp) % TIMER_DURATION
  timerElement.innerText = timeLeft
  
  const timeCorrection = Math.round(timestamp) - timestamp
  setTimeout(step, timeCorrection*1000 + 1000)
}
step()
```

```html
<p id="timer"></p> seconds
```

Try it - open this page up in two different tabs and run it. This is set up to automatically account for the fact that setTimeout doesn't always trigger at the delay you asked it to do so (it'll adjust the next setTimeout with a timeCorrection value to correct these issues).

The basic principle is that we're getting the current timestamp and modding it by the amount of time we want this timer to last (6 seconds in the above example). This value will always be the same for everyone, and will always be a number that ranges from 0 to 5. It will also be a number that counts up every second (which is why we then subtract `(TIMER_DURATION - 1)` from it, to cause the number to count down instead).

Comment: main.js:124 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: The code snippet definitely works when it stands by itself. I only designed it to stand by itself - you'll have to figure out how to best integrate it into your project, with the UI you have, etc (I don't have enough context to explain how best to do this). But, that above error makes it sound like you broke your existing chunk of code, and your `document.getElementById("timer")` is not finding an element with id "timer", so it's returning null. (or something along those lines - check where the line number points you to).

Comment: Perhaps it's because of the order of execution. I certainly didn't use .innerHTML in my code snippet, but maybe you updated it to use that? (BTW - .innerText is prefered over .innerHTML because of security hazards, among other reasons). Anyways, you could also try moving the `const timerElement = document.getElementById('timer')` line into the function. If that fixes the issue, it means your script tag that's running this code was above the place in the DOM that actually contained the element with id "timer". (so another fix is to move the script tag, or listen for DOMContentLoaded event)

Comment: is posible to stop the step() function while the roulette is spining,then, when mi function stoproulette() finish, call the function step() and its start from 25 seg again?

Comment: Will it be stopped for the exact same amount of time every time? Let's say you wanted to show the results for 10 seconds - you can just make the countdown timer go for 35 seconds instead of 25, and do a little logic so the timer is "unpaused" when timeLeft < 25, and "paused" (show a different UI) when 25 <= timeLeft < 35.

Comment: The roulette have a random angle for rotate, so the time is always different, but i think i can solve it. Other of the problem that i have, is the result of the random angle, it is different for each client, do u know some way to set it equal for all the clients?

Comment: Note that in the above solution, I'm working under the assumption that you're wanting to try and get this all done in the browser, without custom coding a server. This will severely limit you on the kinds of features you can add. But, if you want to add a random angle such that each browser independentally show the same random angle without communicating with each other, you can use a pseudo-random number generator, seeded a rounded timestamp of the start of the countdown. Just know that the end-user can use the same algorithm to figure what random angles will happen in the future.

Comment: I also don't think you can get the above solution to work if each round takes a random amount of time - the solution relies on being able to quickly tie a specific timestamp to how far into a round you are - which is only possible if the rounds happen at a fixed interval apart from each other. It still might be possible to do without a server, but it'll be much more difficult.

Comment: Did you know how to send the javascript variables to php, and then, to de database? i'm in trouble with that.

Comment: To tell or ask PHP something, you have to send a REST request with fetch. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API. The following page looks like it'll tell you how to connect to a database from PHP https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_mysql.htm - these are some really broad questions, you'll need to read through some guides and familiarize yourself with the basics.

Comment: this is the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67864572/run-javascript-every-25-secs-in-server-and-insert-into-in-sql-database