# Run javascript every 25 secs in server and insert into in sql database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I need to run this javascript function one time every 25 seconds and save it into mi sql database.
Right now i can do it, but it inserts one time every 25 seconds per client, and i want just once time without care how many clients are online. So i need to run it in the server, no in each client. But i dont know how to do it.

```
function calc_spin_time(){
    function num_rand(){
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*((20)+20)-20);
        return num;}
    spinTimeTotal = Math.random() * 3 + 4 * 1000 + num_rand();
    spinAngleStart = Math.random() * 10 + 10;
    //I need to insert spinTimeTotal and SpinAngleStart into mi sql database
}
```

Comment: make endpoint like `/spin_data.php` then in that code, select from db with `WHERE last_update < now() - interval 25 second`, if it finds none create new values and update, else return what it already has, then turn calc_spin_time into an ajax call

Comment: I dont understand your idea :(

Comment: So, you're basically wanting to translate that function into PHP? You're going to have to go through some PHP tutorials (if needed) and try to get a grasp on how to use PHP, then come back with your best attempt, and we can help you with any specific bugs you might have from that attempt.

Comment: And then you're going to need to learn how to use websockets or server sent events to broadcast the information to all users who have joined the specific game in question

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is going to involve a Cron job of some kind. To accurately help it seems like more information is needed on the type of database and how the function is getting fired. There is a [serverless mechanism I know of called Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) from Firebase.

Comment: its a roulette, i want to insert in the sql databse, the random angle to start spinning, and the random time it will be spinning. and then use them in the javascript of each client, so all the clients gonna have the same roulette result